# Mac App Store Search API?

Tags: api, search, mac-app-store

Does anyone know where to get the Mac App Store Search API? I already know this site -> http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html, and there's a great API to search the iOS App Store. The search results are returned in JSON format.

But where to get this for the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That API will do what you need - try querying with entity `macSoftware`.

Here's an example that queries for Sparrow (the email client):

http://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=macSoftware&term=Sparrow

Comment: Anyone know if you can use this API publicly? No legal issues?

Comment: None I'm aware of - I use this API to run http://beathound.com (I asked Apple's affiliate team, and they were fine with it).